# C# WPF MediaElement Not opening video in XP

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaelement

I have a strange problem.

I have a project that I have that simply opens up an mp4 video file and plays it. I have an event handler which I set a breakpoint in, and it gets into the Media_Opened handler I have and play it under Windows 7/64bit, but it does not even enter the handler when I play the same thing in WindowsXP 32bit.

Is there some compatibility issue that I am not aware of?

note: I am compiling in 32 bit mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF MediaElement requires a specific version of Windows Media Player so make sure that you have the latest version installed (This might have been the default on windows 7 but not in XP)... also make sure that you have the required codecs (Can it play in media player)!

PS. Also based on the MSDN docs, it looks like it required XP SP3 but not sure if this is a actual requirement thou!!!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx

Comment: I made sure that the latest Windows Media Player was installed on the machine (Windows Media Player 11 32-bit) and that the necessary codecs were installed, and it worked afterwards. Thanks!