# Unable to play MedialElement in Windows XP

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-xp, mediaelement

I have a WPF application which has a MediaElement control. The software runs perfectly ok in Windows 7 but runs into trouble when I try to run in Windows XP. In Windows XP, the software runs but won't play the media files. At first I thought, this is a codec issue, however the Media Player in XP can play the files. By the way I am copying the Debug folder to Windows XP and executing the application from there.

*I am kind of stuck here. Would really appreciate, if you can share your thoughts/solution.*

Comment: I just checked, in the MediaFailed Event, following exception is shown: insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Answer (score 0):

i was facing same issue. see if this helps

[C# WPF MediaElement Not opening video in XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714507/c-sharp-wpf-mediaelement-not-opening-video-in-xp)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx